# How to split the output into different files?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell, sed, pipe

I have a input file like

```
 foo xxx yyy zzz
 foo xxx yyy zzz
 foo xxx yyy zzz
 foo xxx yyy zzz
 bar xxx yyy zzz
 bar xxx yyy zzz
 foo xxx yyy zzz
 ..
```

How to split the input file by line, into `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`, depending on the existence of `foo` and `bar` at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -E '^foo' input.txt > foo.txt
grep -E '^bar' input.txt > bar.txt
```

mbp-000234:~ dmourati$ cat foo.txt

```
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz
```

mbp-000234:~ dmourati$ cat bar.txt

```
bar xxx yyy zzz
bar xxx yyy zzz
```

Comment: THis method definitely work, but it require two scan to the file..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, and make any chages if need since i have not tried to run it.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { foo="foo.txt"; bar="bar.txt" }
    {if ($1 == "foo")
         $0 >> foo;
     else
             $0 >> bar;
    }' sourcefilename
```

Comment: -1: the *variables* `foo` and `bar` are empty. You need a string on the right-hand-side of the redirection.

Comment: instead of -1 you might have edited it if you know the correct script, i have just given suggestion, i have not tried it. I already mention in my ans.

Comment: well, fix it and I'll remove my downvote

Comment: My edit is awaiting review. However, and the OP will need to provide an opinion, if your code sees a line beginning with "qux", that line will be added to "bar.txt" -- I suspect the OP would prefer "qux.txt"

Answer (score 1):

```
grep ^foo input.txt > foo.txt
grep ^bar input.txt > bar.txt
```

^ will make sure you only match the beginning of the line, so it will work even if the rest of the line looks like:

```
foo xxx yyy zzz bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ f = $1 ".txt"; print > f }' file
```

Comment: would you please elaborate how above script executes.

Comment: For each line, set a variable `f` with the value of the first field concatenated with the string ".txt" (the awk concatenation "operator" is to put expressions side-by-side). Then print the file to the file named in the variable `f`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also distribute the file stream with `tee` and then split in parallel:

```
<file tee >(grep '^foo' > foo.txt) >(grep '^bar' > bar.txt) > /dev/null
```

Result:

```
$ tail -n+1 foo.txt bar.txt
==> foo.txt <==
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz
foo xxx yyy zzz

==> bar.txt <==
bar xxx yyy zzz
bar xxx yyy zzz
```

Comment: `tail -n+1`? That a pretty obscure way to say `cat`.

Comment: @glennjackman: it has the extra benefit of including the file names in the output.